# Rspec render_template equivalent for Sinatra?

Tags: rspec, sinatra, rspec-rails

I'm building a Sinatra app currently that will be outputting JSON templates as part of an API.  When testing with rails and the rspec-rails gem I was able to call:

```
response.should render_template('template-name')
```

However since I'm not using Rails I'm assuming this won't work.  What's the alternative to use for Sinatra for testing the json output?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some [docs on using Rack Test with RSpec here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html), but this is how I set my stuff up. By wrapping the app in a module's class method it makes it a lot easier to run in the specs, then it's just a case of validating the response via `last_response.body` (which is the short answer to your question).

```
# config.ru

require 'rubygems'
require "bundler/setup"

root = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__)
require File.join( root , "./app/config.rb" )

# everything was moved into a separate module/file 
# to make it easier to set up tests

map "/" do
  run HelloWorld.app
end
```

---

```
# app/config.rb
require 'main'

module HelloWorld
  def self.app
    Rack::Builder.app do
      # middleware setup here, cookies etc
      run App
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/main.rb
require 'sinatra/base'

module HelloWorld
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    get "/", :provides => :json do
      {key: "value"}.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

require 'rspec'
Spec_dir = File.expand_path( File.dirname __FILE__ )

require 'rack/test'

Dir[ File.join( Spec_dir, "/support/**/*.rb")].each do |f|
  require f
end
```

---

```
# spec/support/shared/all_routes.rb

require 'hello_world'  # <-- your sinatra app

shared_context "All routes" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  let(:app){
    HelloWorld.app 
  }
end

shared_examples_for "Any route" do
  subject { last_response }
  it { should be_ok }
end
```

---

```
# spec/hello_world_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'getting some JSON' do
  include_context "All pages"

  let(:expected) {
    '{"key": "value"}'
  }

  before do
    get '/', {}, {"HTTP_ACCEPT" => "application/json" }
  end
  it_should_behave_like "Any route"

  subject { last_response.body }
  it { should == expected }
end
```